# Why is only one server throwing the error "Array to String Conversion"?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, lamp

Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
        foreach($_GET['Inventory'] as $fld => $val) {
           print_r("Field: " . $fld . " Value: " . $val . '</br>');
            if($val != '' && !is_null($val))
                if($fld != 'searchoption')
                    $perma .=  $fld . '=' . $val . '&';
        }
```

print_r() is the cause of the error, but I'm only getting this error on one server. This server recently went through a new installation of Ubuntu (upgraded to 14.04 fresh install) and LAMPP. This is the same (as far as I can tell) source code as the other ones are running, but for some reason this error is persistent here.

I'm not familiar with php-apache modules and I can't shake the feeling that the system is missing a core component that will fix this.

**EDIT (more info):** One on server instead of throwing an error it displays "Array" in the place of the array, if there is indeed an array in $val. I'm not looking to change the code, but rather find out what might cause this.

**OUTPUT FROM THE WORKING SERVER AFTER DOING A SEARCH:**

```
Field: searchoption Value: Array
Field: parentBarcode Value:
Field: barcode Value:
Field: room Value:
Field: fixedAssetTag Value:
Field: hostDomainName Value:
Field: ipAddress Value: test
Field: macAddress Value:
Field: serialNumber Value:
Field: purchaseOrder Value:
Field: accountNumber Value:
Field: searchscope Value: 1
```

**EDIT: The source codes are exactly the same on both servers.**

Loaded Apache modules on not working server:

```
//both servers have these modules loaded
=   core_module (static)                        
=   so_module (static)      
=   http_module (static)
=   log_config_module (static)
=   logio_module (static)
=   alias_module (shared)
=   auth_basic_module (shared)
=   authn_file_module (shared)
=   authz_host_module (shared)
=   authz_user_module (shared)
=   autoindex_module (shared)
=   cgi_module (shared)
=   deflate_module (shared)
=   dir_module (shared)
=   env_module (shared)
=   mime_module (shared)
=   mpm_prefork_module (shared)
=   negotiation_module (shared)
=   php5_module (shared)
=   setenvif_module (shared)
=   status_module (shared)

//Server with error has these extra modules loaded
+   authz_core_module (shared)
+   authn_core_module (shared)
+   version_module (static)
+   unixd_module (static)
+   access_compat_module (shared)
+   rewrite_module (shared)     
+   watchdog_module (static)
+   filter_module (shared)

//Working server has these extra modules loaded
- authz_groupfile_modeul (shared)
- authz_default_module (shared)
- reqtimeout_module (shared)
```

Comment: its possible that `$val` could be an array.

Comment: Try print_r($_GET['Inventory']); before that code, to make sure the input is what you're expecting. Since you're processing url parameters it is quite possible that a server change could have caused a problem without the php changing.

Comment: print_r is used to recursively print a complex variable. You want to simply print, not print_r. So, change print_r to print. Then, it is apparent that one of the values in the array is, itself, an array. So, at least once, a $val is an array. You cannot concatenate an array as though it is a string.

Comment: I'm not looking to do changes to the code, but rather I'd like to find out why it works on one server and not the other (the exact same line of code). On one server instead of throwing an error, in the display field it says "Array".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error likely exists on both servers: you're trying to output an array as a string. This is the problem you should fix. You're probably only seeing the error *message* on one server because this server has a stricter setting for the PHP configuration variable `error_reporting`.

I'd suggest separating the logger line into something like:

```
print_r($fld);
print_r($val);
```

which will work regardless of the variable types.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, but please elaborate more regarding the `error_reporting` variable (where do I find it and how is it set?). I just need to find out why one server responds differently than the other and configure them to be the same.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting - this config values controls the severity of errors you want PHP to report. Array to string conversion is not a particularly serious error, since it's unlikely to be application breaking.

Comment: I'm going to just fix the code instead of changing the variable. I found out this happened of the PHP version used (one was running 5.3.10 and the other 5.5.9). I will accept this as the answer if you reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php (it mentions the change of the default error_reporting value from version to version) since that was my original question and it will make this a good answer for future users.

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't answer the question per se, I'd like to suggest a better way.

It looks like your code is trying to get the contents of `$_GET['Inventory']` and create a query string from them, ignoring all blank entries as well as the key `searchoption`.

Try this code:

```
$inventory = $_GET['Inventory'];
$inventory = array_filter($inventory); // remove blanks
if( isset($inventory['searchoption'])) unset($inventory['searchoption']);
$result = http_build_query($inventory);
```

In particular, this will handle arrays just fine.

Comment: Though this doesn't answer my question, I appreciate the suggestion since it's an improvement on the code.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Fountain said, one of the servers had a stricter setting for the error_reporting variable.

What had happened was that I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 and with it I installed all the latest software versions, including PHP 5.5. The other server runs PHP 5.3. As it turns out, PHP 5.5 has a stricter error_reporting setting by default (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)). This answers the **WHY** the error was thrown on one server and not the other.

There are a few ways to change this setting; one would be to change the error_repoting option setting in php.ini (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini for me). What I ended up doing was I changed the code to print "Array" if the variable was an array instead of trying to concatenate it, which is what caused the error to be thrown.